# build xls files in R with a header on top of column names

Tags: r, excel

I have several hundred `xls` files that have incorrect data in them.

I need to open them make corrections and save them.

Making corrections is a trivial matter so I already wrote the code for that, trick is that each sheet has one table which starts on row 3 and first two rows contain legal header.

I am accustomed to using `readxl` package but it does not provide tools for saving spreadsheets. So today I have been experimenting with `xslx` package but I'm not quite sure how to make it work.

In `readr` I was able to use following to write `csv` files with a disclaimer:

```
write_csv(Disclaimer, filepath,col_names = FALSE)
write_csv(my.data.frame,filepath, col_names = TRUE,append =TRUE)
```

In `xlsx` this doesn't work:

```
write.xlsx(filepath,Disclaimer,"Sheet1",col.names = FALSE)
write.xlsx(filepath,my.data.frame,"Sheet1",col.names = TRUE,append=TRUE)
```

This yeilds a java error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet of this name

So my question is how can you write a `xls` file(alternatively `xlsx` but not `csv`), such that it has a header above the acutual table.

For the record my workbooks have two sheets, both sheets have the disclaimer, but they contain different tables.

I really wish I could move away from excel files but I need to maintain original format.

Also I'm open to using other packages but I'm not familiar with others(reasearching `XLConnect` as we speak).

Comment: why don't you try `readr::write_excel_csv`?

Comment: Hi @yeedle thanks for the input, this created a `csv` file even when I overwrote file extension to `xls`(warning came up that extension doesn't match file format). Here is how I tested this `write_excel_csv(data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1),b=c("A","B","C","D")),"./test.xls")`, is this what you had in mind?

Comment: yes. my bad. I thought this writes `xls` files

Comment: no worries thanks for trying

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!!!

`xlsx` has other low level functions that let you build each sheet piece by piece.

See my test code bellow:

```
wb <- createWorkbook(type = "xls")
sh1 <- createSheet(wb,sheetName = "Sheet1")
addDataFrame(data.frame("Disclaimer"=c("Disclaimer")),sheet = sh1,row.names = FALSE,startRow = 1,col.names = FALSE)
addDataFrame(data.frame("Col1" = c(1,2,3),"Col2"=4:6),sheet = sh1,row.names = FALSE,startRow = 2)

sh2 <- createSheet(wb,sheetName = "Sheet2")
addDataFrame(data.frame("Disclaimer"=c("Disclaimer")),sheet = sh2,row.names = FALSE,startRow = 1,col.names = FALSE)
addDataFrame(data.frame("Col1" = c(1,2,3),"Col2"=4:6),sheet = sh2,row.names = FALSE,startRow = 2)

saveWorkbook(wb,"test_wb.xls")
```